# XSLT: How to categorize individual elements which are located on the same level

Tags: xslt, nested-loops

Dear community,
I would like to transform an initial xml which has this format:

```
<h2>title1</h2>
<div>sometext1</div>
<div>sometext2</div>
<h2>title2</h2>
<div>sometext3</div>
<div>sometext4</div>
<h2>title3</h2>
<div>sometext5</div>
<div>sometext6</div>
```

into

```
<cat name="title1">
<div>sometext1</div>
<div>sometext2</div>
</cat>
<cat name="title2">
<div>sometext3</div>
<div>sometext4</div>
</cat>
<cat name="title3">
<div>sometext5</div>
<div>sometext6</div>
</cat>
```

I have tried to execute a double for-each and create a variable to hold the "select" option to execute the inner for-each, but seems like it is required to use the node-set() function. Even if I try to include it, it does not work. Do you have any thoughts on how to resolve this issue, using XSLT 1.0 and preferrably without using any other namespaces?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge adjacent sibling nodes with XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091951/merge-adjacent-sibling-nodes-with-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing this that does not depend on nested loops.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="x" match="div" use="preceding-sibling::h2[1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(name()='div')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h2">
    <cat name="{text()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('x',.)"/>
    </cat>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It first builds an index (xsl:key) that maps each div to its immediately preceding h2. Then we have a simple identity transform that skips the div entries.  For each h2 encountered we generate the `<cat>` and then output the `<div...>` tags indexed from that h2.