# Selecting nodes with conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf

I am trying to transform XML files, but I am blocked. The idea is to aggregate every elements from `<ore:Aggregation>` node until the next one. It is some kind of itemization. But I can't get more than 1 `edm:WebResource` per created `dc:item`.

### XML :

```
<rdf:RDF>
    <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="id1">
        <some:crap/>
    </ore:Aggregation>
    <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="id1">
        <some:crap/>
    </edm:ProvidedCHO>
    <edm:WebResource rdf:about="some/random/url"> 
        <some:crap/>
    </edm:WebResource>
            ...
               (n 'edm:WebResource' nodes)
            ...
    <edm:WebResource rdf:about="some/random/url">
        <some:crap/>    
    </edm:WebResource>

    <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="id2">
        <some:crap/>
    </ore:Aggregation>
    <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="id2">
        <some:crap/>
    </edm:ProvidedCHO>
    <edm:WebResource rdf:about="some/random/url"> 
        <some:crap/>
    </edm:WebResource>
            ...
               (n 'edm:WebResource' nodes)
            ...
    <edm:WebResource rdf:about="some/random/url">
        <some:crap/>    
    </edm:WebResource>

        ... and on and on ...
</rdf:RDF>
```

### XSL

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/rdf:RDF/ore:Aggregation"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/rdf:RDF/ore:Aggregation">
    <rdf:RDF>
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <dc:item>
                <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($fileName, '_item', position())"/>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::edm:ProvidedCHO[1]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::edm:WebResource[1]"/>

                <!-- WHERE IT SUCKS -->
                <xsl:if test="local-name(following-sibling::*[3]) = 'edm:WebResource'">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[3]"/>
                </xsl:if>                    
                <!-- ./WHERE IT SUCKS -->


            </dc:item>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </rdf:RDF>
</xsl:template>
```

Another attempt which bring too many nodes :

```
<!-- WHERE IT SUCKS -->
<xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[local-name (preceding::*[1]) = 'ore:Aggregation']"/>
<!-- ./WHERE IT SUCKS -->
```

### Expected Output

```
<!-- ITEM N1 -->
<rdf:RDF>
    <dc:item rdf:about="some.concat.string"/>
    <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="id1">
        <some:crap/>
    </ore:Aggregation>
    <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="id1">
        <some:crap/>
    </edm:ProvidedCHO>
    <edm:WebResource rdf:about="some/random/url"> 
        <some:crap/>
    </edm:WebResource>
</rdf:RDF>

<!-- ITEM N2 -->
<rdf:RDF>
     <dc:item rdf:about="some.concat.string"/>
     <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="id1">
     <etc/>
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output in this case? Also, are you using XLST1.0 or XLST2.0? If you are using 2.0, this sounds like it might be a case for use `xsl:for-each-group` together with `group-starting-with`. (See http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html).

Comment: I just add the ouput to the post, while having a look on  xsl:for-each-group

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: It's XSLT version 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, this looks like it would be a job for `xsl:for-each-group` (See http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html). In particular, using it with `group-starting-with`

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="ore:Aggregation">
```

This would be done when positioned on the parent `rdf:RDF` element, and will arrange all the child elements into groups, with the `ore:Aggregration` being the start of each group. The code within `xsl:for-each-group` then gets called once for each `ore:Aggregation` element, and you can then use the `current-group()` function to access all elements within the group.

Try this XSLT for starters

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:rdf="rdf" xmlns:ore="ore" xmlns:dc="dc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="ore:Aggregation">
            <rdf:RDF xmlns:edm="edm" xmlns:ore="ore" xmlns:some="some">
                <dc:item rdf:about="{concat('item', position())}" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </rdf:RDF>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the output XML this generates is not well-formed, as it lacks a single root element. It would be much better if one were added, not just to make it well formed, but then the namespace declarations would also go in one place:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:rdf="rdf" xmlns:ore="ore" xmlns:dc="dc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
        <rdf:root xmlns:edm="edm" xmlns:ore="ore" xmlns:some="some">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="ore:Aggregation">
                <rdf:RDF>
                    <dc:item rdf:about="{concat('item', position())}" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                </rdf:RDF>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </rdf:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) in creating the `rdf:about` which further reduces the amount of code needed.

Comment: Thanks, working great but I updated a bit the expected output. I would like to refine the new structure, and without any namespaces within 'dc:item'. Sorry I am still struggling with what the templates are matching or applied.

Comment: I've changed my answer to reflect the new structure. Strictly speaking, the location of the namespace declaration would not necessarily make the XML different from a semantic point of view. They do need to go somewhere though.

Comment: I removed the <rdf:root> element and it makes exactly what I am looking for thanks. But do you know why every element within <rdf:RDF> get namespaces declaration ? Can't I limit ns declarations only within <rdf:RDF> elements ?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this case a few times before and the best solution that I've been able to come up with involves set manipulation.

In a way this makes sense, since you want all of the nodes after each ore:Aggregation until the next ore:Aggregation.

Put another way, you want *all* of the following nodes *except* for next ore:Aggregation *and* everything that follows it.

Thankfully in XSLT 2.0 we have set manipulation operators, so we don't have to jump through convoluted hoops that we would have had to do in XSLT 1.0.

Try this XPATH

```
following-sibling::node() except 
  (following-sibling::ore:Aggregation | 
   following-sibling::ore:Aggregation/following-sibling::node())
```

This should give you the node-set that you expect.

This pattern works generally every time you are attempting to sort a flat list of elements into some sort of result structure.  For example, the problem I had was finding all elements that had a particular attribute and then grouping them into one.

So, the general solution is (in pseudo-code)

This would be a little simpler if we could specify both the terminal tag and it's following siblings at the same time, but this doesn't actually read too bad.

```
following-sibling::node() except 
  (following-sibling::{next-node-selection-criteria} | 
   following-sibling::{next-node-selection-criteria}/following-sibling::node())
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2093596/125901 for another technique using for-each-group.  I didn't test that, however, and I find this XPath set manipulation easier to read and less verbose.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually very useful as I changed my goal.